# adding a image to layerlist item with shape

Tags: android, layer, shapes

i have a xml as below i trying to add a image from drawable folder but its not working.

`<solid android:color="#FFF"/>` this is where i need to add image from drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#225786" />
        <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
```

is there any other way that i can add i tried with layer list with item this is how i have tried

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background">
        <shape>
            <solid/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#225786" />
            <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item> 
  </layer-list>
```

Now its not displaying the border which i am doing with shape it only adds a background to it.

Comment: item android:drawable="YourDrawableID". You need to rephrase your question, i don't understand.

Comment: Please brief your question . i am unable to understand.

Comment: guys i want to add a background image to the shape which i have drawn

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your want a background with border, try this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" />
    <item 
        <shape>
            <solid/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#225786" />
            <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item> 
  </layer-list>
```

and if your just want a background, try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >

</bitmap>
```

Comment: ok thanks it works but only a small issue the image which i am setting as a background is square and the shape which i am adding is of rounded corners so the background image sharp edges are showing so can we add some stroke to that?

Comment: I don't know how, but maybe you should just play with background image

Comment: Am not getting corner radius effect?