# Is it possible to specify border in android button with keeping its background?

Tags: android, android-drawable, imagebutton, setbackground, shapedrawable

Is it possible to specify border in android button in its Activity?
I want keep button `png` background and add specify border to that and remove it or change color of that dynamically.

A puzzle board consists of a few buttons in order to be selected, if the choice was incorrect to take red border.

Comment: I guess you have to use a layer list with a bitmap and shapes. See this post, it´s similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377156/adding-a-image-to-layerlist-item-with-shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ImageButton` : use your png image as `android:src` and for background border add a drawable xml .

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```

in `res/drawable/border.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/stroke_color"></stroke>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

To change the shape Border color programetically use:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
GradientDrawable backgroundGradient = (GradientDrawable) button.getBackground();
backgroundGradient.setStroke(5, Color.RED);  // set stroke width and stroke color
```