# How to add stroke/border for drawable image used inside button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a button , inside which there is an image and text
I used **shape.xml** to give css to button

[image]

How can i give css (stroke/border) to the image inside this button

[image]

the **image** is given as **drawableTop** inside the

Code:

```
<Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="CollegeNews"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/doctor"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:drawableBackground="#95a5a6"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Doctor"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            />
```

Shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="#FFF"
    />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border in shape xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698927/border-in-shape-xml)

Comment: its about external border of shape, i want border for internal elements in shape

Comment: did you try adding stroke on your shape?

Comment: yes, its giving border outside the white

Comment: I want stroke just of the image, not for whole box

Comment: as what my understanding the drawableTop you add is an image file right? in order to customized it make it like shape then add the image as background like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377429/5870896

Comment: as what my understanding the drawableTop you add is an image file right? in order to customized it make it like shape then add the image as background like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377429/5870896